# iphone - Sqlite3 Database Locked Exception

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I tried many methods, in order to get rid of this error, but I didn't succeed. I am a newbie and I tried to figure out from all the other questions and also tried some advices, but it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
- (void) addObiectAsigurat
{
sqlite3 *database = nil;
sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;

if(sqlite3_open([[Database getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{

    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "INSERT INTO ObiectAsigurat (IdIntern, TipObiect, JSONText) Values(?, ?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [IdIntern UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 2, TipObiect); 
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [JSONText UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else {
        sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```

If I use this at the end of this method

---

```
}
else sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);

sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

then my error looks like this:

```
Assertion failure in -[YTOObiectAsigurat addObiectAsigurat] 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while inserting data. 'database is locked''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ba3012 0x16fae7e 0x1ba2e78 0x1190665 0xb6661 0x3d534 0x63a82 0x1200589 0x11fe652 0x11ff89a 0x11fe60d 0x11fe785 0x114ba68 0x2696911 0x2695bb3 0x26d3cda 0x1b458fd 0x26d435c 0x26d42d5 0x25be250 0x1b26f3f 0x1b2696f 0x1b49734 0x1b48f44 0x1b48e1b 0x1ad27e3 0x1ad2668 0x63effc 0xf4d5 0x2615)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

If I use this

---

```
    sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
    }
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

I get bad Thread 1:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS

libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3_finalize:
0x37fce0:  pushl  %ebp
0x37fce1:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x37fce3:  pushl  %ebx
0x37fce4:  pushl  %edi
0x37fce5:  pushl  %esi
0x37fce6:  subl   $28, %esp
0x37fce9:  calll  0x37fcee                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 14
0x37fcee:  popl   %eax
0x37fcef:  movl   %eax, -16(%ebp)
0x37fcf2:  xorl   %edi, %edi
0x37fcf4:  movl   8(%ebp), %esi
0x37fcf7:  testl  %esi, %esi
0x37fcf9:  je     0x37fe16                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 310
0x37fcff:  movl   (%esi), %ebx
0x37fd01:  testl  %ebx, %ebx
0x37fd03:  je     0x37fd1f                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 63
0x37fd05:  cmpl   $2687084183, 60(%ebx)
0x37fd0c:  jne    0x37fd1f                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 63
0x37fd0e:  movl   48(%esi), %eax
0x37fd11:  cmpl   $3186757027, %eax
0x37fd16:  je     0x37fd6a                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 138
0x37fd18:  cmpl   $1369188723, %eax
0x37fd1d:  je     0x37fd6a                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 138
0x37fd1f:  movl   -16(%ebp), %esi
0x37fd22:  leal   726721(%esi), %eax
0x37fd28:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x37fd2c:  movl   $21, (%esp)
0x37fd33:  calll  0x37b7c0                  ; sqlite3_log
0x37fd38:  leal   705186(%esi), %eax
0x37fd3e:  movl   %eax, 12(%esp)
0x37fd42:  leal   705450(%esi), %eax
0x37fd48:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x37fd4c:  movl   $67126, 8(%esp)
0x37fd54:  movl   $21, (%esp)
0x37fd5b:  calll  0x37b7c0                  ; sqlite3_log
0x37fd60:  movl   $21, %edi
0x37fd65:  jmp    0x37fe16                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 310
0x37fd6a:  movl   12(%ebx), %edi
0x37fd6d:  testl  %edi, %edi
0x37fd6f:  je     0x37fd80                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 160
0x37fd71:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x37fd74:  movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x37fd77:  calll  *759034(%eax)
0x37fd7d:  movl   48(%esi), %eax
0x37fd80:  movl   %edi, -20(%ebp)
0x37fd83:  cmpl   $3186757027, %eax
0x37fd88:  je     0x37fd93                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 179
0x37fd8a:  xorl   %edi, %edi
0x37fd8c:  cmpl   $1369188723, %eax
0x37fd91:  jne    0x37fd9c                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 188
0x37fd93:  movl   %esi, %ecx
0x37fd95:  calll  0x37ff00                  ; sqlite3VdbeReset
0x37fd9a:  movl   %eax, %edi
0x37fd9c:  movl   60(%esi), %eax
0x37fd9f:  movl   (%esi), %ecx
0x37fda1:  movl   56(%esi), %edx
0x37fda4:  testl  %edx, %edx
0x37fda6:  je     0x37fdad                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 205
0x37fda8:  movl   %eax, 60(%edx)
0x37fdab:  jmp    0x37fdb0                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 208
0x37fdad:  movl   %eax, 4(%ecx)
0x37fdb0:  movl   60(%esi), %eax
0x37fdb3:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x37fdb5:  je     0x37fdbd                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 221
0x37fdb7:  movl   56(%esi), %edx
0x37fdba:  movl   %edx, 56(%eax)
0x37fdbd:  movl   $3053896648, 48(%esi)
0x37fdc4:  movl   $0, (%esi)
0x37fdca:  movl   %esi, %edx
0x37fdcc:  calll  0x378cd0                  ; sqlite3VdbeDeleteObject
0x37fdd1:  cmpb   $0, 50(%ebx)
0x37fdd5:  jne    0x37fddf                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 255
0x37fdd7:  cmpl   $3082, %edi
0x37fddd:  jne    0x37fe00                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 288
0x37fddf:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x37fde2:  movl   $0, 8(%esp)
0x37fdea:  movl   $7, 4(%esp)
0x37fdf2:  calll  0x37d090                  ; sqlite3Error
0x37fdf7:  movb   $0, 50(%ebx)
0x37fdfb:  movl   $7, %edi
0x37fe00:  andl   44(%ebx), %edi
0x37fe03:  movl   -20(%ebp), %eax
0x37fe06:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x37fe08:  je     0x37fe16                  ; sqlite3_finalize + 310
0x37fe0a:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x37fe0d:  movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x37fe10:  calll  *759042(%eax)
0x37fe16:  movl   %edi, %eax
0x37fe18:  addl   $28, %esp
0x37fe1b:  popl   %esi
0x37fe1c:  popl   %edi
0x37fe1d:  popl   %ebx
0x37fe1e:  popl   %ebp
0x37fe1f:  ret
```

These are all my methods for insert, update, delete and select.

```
 - (void) addObiectAsigurat
 {
sqlite3 *database = nil;
sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;

if(sqlite3_open([[Database getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{

    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "INSERT INTO ObiectAsigurat (IdIntern, TipObiect, JSONText) Values(?, ?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [IdIntern UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 2, TipObiect); 
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [JSONText UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else {
        sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

       sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}

- (void) updateObiectAsigurat
{
sqlite3 *database = nil;
sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;

if(sqlite3_open([[Database getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    if(updateStmt == nil) {
        NSString *update = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ObiectAsigurat SET JSONText = ? WHERE IdIntern='%@'", IdIntern];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [update UTF8String], -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [JSONText UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);                       

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else {
        sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
   sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
}


sqlite3_close(database);
}

- (void) deleteObiectAsigurat
{
sqlite3 *database = nil;
sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt = nil;

if(sqlite3_open([[Database getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{

    if(deleteStmt == nil) {
        NSString *delete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM ObiectAsigurat WHERE IdIntern='%@'", IdIntern];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [delete UTF8String], -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else {
        sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
}

sqlite3_close(database);
}

+ (YTOObiectAsigurat *) getObiectAsigurat:(NSString *)idIntern
{
YTOObiectAsigurat * ob = [[YTOObiectAsigurat alloc] init];
sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt = nil;

if (sqlite3_open([[Database getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString * sqlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT IdIntern, TipObiect, JSONText FROM ObiectAsigurat WHERE IdIntern='%@'", idIntern];
    const char *sql = [sqlstring UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            ob._isDirty = YES;

            ob.IdIntern = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
            ob.TipObiect = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 1);
            ob.JSONText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
}

sqlite3_close(database);

return ob;
}

+ (NSMutableArray *) getListaByTipObiect:(int)tip;
{
NSMutableArray * _list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt = nil;

if (sqlite3_open([[Database getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString * sqlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT IdIntern, TipObiect, JSONText FROM ObiectAsigurat WHERE TipObiect=%d",tip];
    const char *sql = [sqlstring UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            YTOObiectAsigurat * ob = [[YTOObiectAsigurat alloc] init];
            ob._isDirty = YES;

            ob.IdIntern = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
            ob.TipObiect = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 1);
            ob.JSONText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];

            [_list addObject:ob];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
}

sqlite3_close(database);

return _list;
}

@end
```

EDIT: I solved my problem very easy.

I didn't finalize and close the database in the method for insert, update, delete, I just reset the statement and then make it nil. After this, I declare a method finalize, where I close the database and finalize the statements. Maybe this idea will help somebody.

Comment: Please paste ur error

Comment: are you calling -addObiectAsigurat in a loop?

Comment: @Oleg Yes. in a for loop. I want to insert objects from a nsdictionary.

Comment: Okay, then I will show you a better way how to do it in my updated answer :-) Are you working with your database in any other methods in your application?

Comment: @Oleg yes. I have also select, delete and update methods. If you want I can copy them here.

Comment: Do you call sqlite3_close(database) in each of them?

Comment: @Oleg YES I call that for each of them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24813/discussion-between-maria-stoica-and-oleg)

Comment: I added all the methods for select, insert, update, delete. so that you can see all of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you are closing your database connection in other methods where you work with it.
2. Since you call your method in a loop, there is much more efficient way to work with database when you need bulk insert of data:
   Rebuild your application to loop through your values inside INSERT like this:
   This is only an example, insert proper values here

   ```
   -(void)insertValuesFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {

   sqlite3 * database;

   const char *dbpath = [[Database getDBPath] UTF8String];

   if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
       sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
       const char *sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO ObiectAsigurat (IdIntern) Values(?)";
       sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

       if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
           int hasError = 0;

           for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
               sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [[array objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


               if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                   hasError=1;
                   NSLog(@"Prepare-error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
               }

               sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
           }

           sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

           if( hasError == 0 ) {
               sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
               NSLog(@"inserted successfully");
           }
           else {
               sqlite3_exec(contactDB, "ROLLBACK", 0, 0, 0);
               NSLog(@"can't insert:");
           }
       }
       sqlite3_close(contactDB);
   }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are not committing insert transaction. Search around for how to commit and try some solutions.

following could be helpful

[SQLite 3 C API Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416924/sqlite-3-c-api-transactions)

Ignore if you have already tried that....

Comment: He is making a single INSERT, without TRANSACTIONs so no need to use COMMIT there :-)